# export 'default' (imported as 'Three') was not found in 'three'

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, vue.js

Overview
In main.js, add

```
import Three from 'three'
```

`Vue.use(Three)`

Start dev server with npm run dev.
Expected behavior
The Vue project should load without errors.
Actual behavior
The dev server gives this warning:

```
warning  in ./src/main.js
    7:8-14 "export 'default' (imported as 'Three') was not found in 'three'
```

And the browser's js console displays the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'installed' of undefined
at Function.Vue.use (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:723), <anonymous>:3443:15)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:778), <anonymous>:14:45)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:778)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:660)
at fn (app.js:84)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:964)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:660)
at app.js:709
at app.js:712
```

Answer (score 9):

It's happening because there are no default export made in the ThreeJS library, so you can import everything like this:

```
import * as Three from 'three';
```

Also you don't need the `Vue.use` since this is not VueJS Plugin.

Since there are no default export, you are able to import specific part from ThreeJS, like this:

```
import { Scene } from 'three';
```

Comment: This is old, but just came across this, I get that it can be ignored and still function, bu why is it a warning, how does one get rid of this warning?

Comment: In my case, it was actually *export 'Geometry' [...] not found* as I migrate to/through r125 where the old Geometry representation was deprecated.

I had forgotten one `new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(X)` in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Three.js directly, you need a Vue wrapper around it, you can find one [here](https://github.com/fritx/vue-threejs)

If you do want to use it directly, you have several options:

1. Import it in every file and use it:

   ```
   import Three from 'three'
   Three.doSomething
   ```
2. Import it in the main file and put it on the window object:

   ```
   window.Three = require('Three');
   ```
3. Add it to the Vue instance (preferred way):

   ```
    import Three from 'three';
    Object.definePrototype(Vue.prototype, '$three', { value: Three});
   ```

and then you can refer to it like this: `this.$three`

Answer (score 0):

In vscode,You need to set this [typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_typings-and-automatic-type-acquisition%20in%20preferences)

> Many popular libraries ship with typings files so you get IntelliSense for them automatically. For libraries that do not include typings, VS Code's Automatic Type Acquisition will automatically install community maintained typings file for you.

or import {Scene, PerspectiveCamera, WebGLRenderer, ...other} from 'three'